# CSS em uma página HTML

Tags: html, css, webdesign

[image: Print da Página]

Eu tenho essa página HTML, mas não sei como fazer no meu CSS para conseguir caber 2 desses Retângulos em uma Linha

```
<div id="flex"> <!-- Area Campeoes -->
    <div id="area-principal">
        <div id="area-postagem">
                <!-- Loop --> 
                <div class="caixa-conteudo">
                    <div class="sub-left">
                        <img src="images/aldous.png" width="60">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div id="nome">Aldous</div>
                        <a id="caixa-mini-texto"  href="CarregarChamp?nome=${ champ.nome }">Mostrar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- /Loop -->        
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /Area Campeoes -->
```

Código do CSS

```
#area-principal {
width: 920px;
padding: 15px;}


#area-postagens {
width: 660px;
float: left;}


.caixa-conteudo {
width: 15%;
background: #fff;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 5px;
position: relative;
display: flex;}


.sub-left{
left: 0;}

#nome {
margin-left: 15px;}

#caixa-mini-texto {
margin-top: 13px;
margin-left: 7px;
padding: 5px 9px;
display: block;
background: #f7b600;
color: white;}
```

Comment: Consegue montar um [mcve] na pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só pra mim entender melhor como tentar te ajudar.
Tu queres fazer com que tu tenha  2 blocos de lado, certo?
No caso:
Miya | Belmond
Saber | Alice

Dessa forma?

```
<html>
  <link href="custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <body>
    <div class="bloco"></div>
    <div class="bloco"></div>

    <script src="teste.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

.bloco {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Dessa forma, tens 2 blocos um do lado do outro.
https://prnt.sc/x5nr07

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas não sei como fazer

Comment: Editei minha primeira pergunta pra facilitar a visualização da resposta. Vê se é isso que tu precisa.

Comment: Vlw mano, consegui arrumar o código e o seu código ajudou, não sabia desse tipo de display

Comment: Só uma dica a respeito do teu código.
Tenta organizar ele da seguinte forma:

Div do personagem > nome do personagem (><) foto dele > link de mostrar.
Fica inclusive mais fácil de tu conseguir visualizar e editar teu código depois. Se quiser, eu mando uma resposta com um exemplo

Answer (score 0):

Tu consegue também manter em duas colunas usando o column-count.
Ver se isso te ajuda.

```
#area-postagem {
  width: 660px;
  column-count: 2;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;


/*display: block;*/
/*float: left;*/

}
```